# Getting back a single user Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a call to my backend where I'm trying to find a single user by his generated ID.
[image: My user table]

and here is the code I'm trying to run, but it's not bringing back anything....what am I missing?

```
// @route    GET api/users/:user_id
// @desc     Get User by user ID
// @access   Public
router.get('/users/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      users: req.users._id,
    }).populate('user');

    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });

    return res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server error' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my routes and my getting the user. After some digging I found the correct method to get a single user by ID

```
router.get('/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.params.user_id;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userID).exec();
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-The First Mistake is in you `params`.
-You are passing as prams and expect that it may work as req but it 
 will not .
-So Just pass as req.params it will give you id 
 

So it will look like:

const user = await User.findOne({
 users: req.prams.user_id,  
}).populate('user');
```